# array of spinners on android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm new to android.. & I'm trying to create an Array of 4 `Spinners` (each having the same dynamic options in the list - which are the message1 to message6) for a timetable of sorts. The code worked fine when there was only 1 `Spinner`, but when I created the `Spinner` & `ArrayAdapter` arrays and then then tried to run it, the app crashes. I get the error "Unfortunately, app has stopped." & my running device hangs and i have to restart it.
(I haven't implemented the processing of the spinner selection results yet)
If anyone can help me out here, it'd be great.
Here is my code:

```
public class Activity3 extends Activity {

private Button done;
private Spinner spinner[]= new Spinner[4];
private ArrayAdapter dataAdapter[]= new ArrayAdapter[4];

String message1,message2,message3,message4,message5,message6;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity3);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
     message1 = intent.getStringExtra(Activity2.EXTRA_MESSAGE1);
     message2 = intent.getStringExtra(Activity2.EXTRA_MESSAGE2);
     message3 = intent.getStringExtra(Activity2.EXTRA_MESSAGE3);
     message4 = intent.getStringExtra(Activity2.EXTRA_MESSAGE4);
     message5 = intent.getStringExtra(Activity2.EXTRA_MESSAGE5);
     message6 = intent.getStringExtra(Activity2.EXTRA_MESSAGE6);

    for(int i=1;i<=4;i++) {

        addItemsOnSpinner(i);

    }
}

public void addItemsOnSpinner(int i) {

    String spinner_id="spinner"+i;
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(spinner_id, "id", "com.sample.pat1");
    spinner[i] = ((Spinner) findViewById(resID));
    List<String> subject_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    subject_list.add(message1);
    subject_list.add(message2);
    subject_list.add(message3);
    subject_list.add(message4);
    subject_list.add(message5);
    subject_list.add(message6);

    dataAdapter[i] = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, subject_list);
    dataAdapter[i].setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner[i].setAdapter(dataAdapter[i]);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity3, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: could we also get the error when it crashes ?

Comment: Error: "unfortunately, PAT1 has stopped." And then my running device hangs and i have to restart it.

Comment: Sorry, i meant the description of the exception in your logcat

Comment: Sorry.. my bad. Error : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sample.pat1/com.sample.pat1.Activity3}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
(and a lottt more locations...)

Comment: left you the solution, you're going too far in your spinner table, you're "out of the bounds" of the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)`
and later use `"spinner" + (i+1)`

I believe your ArrayIndexOutOfBounds is causing because you want to call spinner[4] which is out of bounds as your max is spinner[3]

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is right here :

```
for(int i=1;i<=4;i++) {

    addItemsOnSpinner(i);

}
```

The problem is you have 4 spinners, but you forgot that in a loop you begin at 0, so it's "0,1,2,3" so the 4th spinner will have index 3, here you're trying to work like "1,2,3,4" so your 4th spinner has index 4, but you'll try to get the element at index 4 in the spinner tab which means the 5th one, but your table is only 4 length, so you have an "outOfBoundException"

Try changing the loop into

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {

    addItemsOnSpinner(i);

}
```

Hope I helped you

Comment: yep! it worked! thanks a lott slorangex, Bxtr n Lennon fr the solution as well as explanation! :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are trying to add an object at position 4 in the array. Since the array has 4 position like `private Spinner spinner[]= new Spinner[4];` you must add objects using the 0 position until 3 position.